# Unable to receive USB packets

Tags: embedded

I am trying to receive data packets through printer interfaced with PIC32.

I can send setup bytes and receive 8 bit data correctly, but when the data to be received through IN packet is greater than 8 bytes, I cannot receive them correctly after first 8 bytes .

Additional information erroneously posted as an "answer" and moved here:

I am a bit confused , when initiating the read after in token ..the first two bytes come to 341 , as i am trying to read the DEVICE_ID for printer class , they suggest the length of the string sent by the printer .

This is what i am doing while preparing for first in token.

```
BDT_ENTRY *pointbdt;  // pointe to BDT 

pointbdt = BDT_IN; (even BDT)  // 

free(pEP0Data);
pEP0Data=NULL;
   if(!((pointbdt=(BDT_ENTRY*) malloc(sizeof(BDT_ENTRY)))==NULL))  
     {


      pointbdt=BDT_IN;

      pEP0Data=(BYTE *) malloc(sizeof(8));  // pointer to buffer

    pointbdt->STAT.Val=0;         
      pointbdt->ADR=ConvertToPhysicalAddress(pEP0Data);        
    pointbdt->CNT=8;
    pointbdt->STAT.BSTALL=0;
    pointbdt->STAT.DTSEN=1;
    pointbdt->STAT.DTS=1;
    pointbdt->STAT.UOWN=1;
      U1EP0 = 0x4D;
      U1ADDR = 0x00;
      U1TOK =10010000; //in  


  }
```

Then after this is guess when another SOF interrupt happens i have to toggle the DTSEN and also the pointbdt should point to the BDT_IN_ODD (odd BDT) . The byte that i get after 8 byte are corrupt .

I am trying to print the values through hyperterminal on pc.

---

I am a bit confused , when initiating the read after in token ..the first two bytes come to 341 , as i am trying to read the DEVICE_ID for printer class , they suggest the length of the string sent by the printer .

This is what i am doing while preparing for first in token.

```
BDT_ENTRY *pointbdt;  // pointe to BDT 

pointbdt = BDT_IN; (even BDT)  // 

free(pEP0Data);
pEP0Data=NULL;
   if(!((pointbdt=(BDT_ENTRY*) malloc(sizeof(BDT_ENTRY)))==NULL))  
     {


      pointbdt=BDT_IN;

      pEP0Data=(BYTE *) malloc(sizeof(8));  // pointer to buffer

    pointbdt->STAT.Val=0;         
      pointbdt->ADR=ConvertToPhysicalAddress(pEP0Data);        
    pointbdt->CNT=8;
    pointbdt->STAT.BSTALL=0;
    pointbdt->STAT.DTSEN=1;
    pointbdt->STAT.DTS=1;
    pointbdt->STAT.UOWN=1;
      U1EP0 = 0x4D;
      U1ADDR = 0x00;
      U1TOK =10010000; //in  


  }
```

Then after this is guess when another  SOF interrupt happens i have to toggle the DTSEN and also the pointbdt should point to the BDT_IN_ODD  (odd BDT) .
The byte that i get after 8 byte are corrupt .

I am trying to print the values through hyperterminal on pc.

Comment: It's `receive` (not "recieve")

Comment: You're going to need to give us more information.  Is the 9th, 10th, etc byte corrupted?  Do you not have buffer space to put it in?  It's not clear from what you've provided what the overall problem is, so we have no way of helping...

Comment: It looks like you are only allocating space for 8 bytes, and setting that as a fixed transfer size.  Also, you probably don't want to be doing a malloc and free for every packet, but rather have a consistent buffer that you re-use.  If there's any chance your hardware implementation is limited to USB low speed, that would also formally impose an 8-byte limitation.